# Increase Precision Touchpad two-finger scrolling speed?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, touchpad

The scrolling speed is too slow. It is a Microsoft Precision Trackpad on Windows 10, but I cannot find any option for scrolling speed in the Settings -> Devices -> Touchpad.

Changing the wheel speed of mouse did not affect the scrolling speed of the trackpad, but only the mouse wheel.

Is there anything like a Registry hack to adjust the scrolling speed of the Precision Touchpad?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the model of your laptop.

Comment: I think the specific model of the laptop would not matter, as this trackpad (Precision Trackpad) is controlled by Windows 10 itself, not by a manufacturer driver.

Answer (score 15):

The magic key is:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch\Friction
```

Lower is better. Much lower. Simply reboot your machine for changes to instantly take effect.

Comment: You're not joking when you say magic.  I thought it would increase the speed, which it doesn't exactly, it makes it so you can go way further quickly...  It works beautifully for me (I set it to 1)

Comment: Spot on. Worked beautifully on Dell XPS 7590's trackpad, and overall starts to resemble  the feel of the MacBook Pro.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on ASUS laptops (FX505DV) but +1 anyway for other manufactures.

Comment: Fantastic! Works on my Thinkpad Gen6. So strange that it's not a tuneable in the UI.

Comment: This seems to boost the momentum flick of the precision trackpad. But is there any way to boost the scaling (inches moved to amount scrolled)? It's still super slow. I don't find i intuitive to flick every time I need to scroll fast

Comment: This worked great for me on a Dell Precision 7730, two finger scroll was painfully slow.  I kicked friction all the way to 0, not a huge fan of inertia but 10 is not bad, might lower it a bit. Keep in mind, DWORD values are HEX (0 - F = 0 - 15)

Answer (score 3):

Under this key:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch

Setting "Friction" and "Interia" to a decimal value of 10 for both works for me. This is for my Lenovo Ideapad 330s 14ast.

Make sure you restart your laptop to apply these changes :)

Answer (score 2):

So I still haven't found a clean solution to boost the sensitivity scaling on two finger scrolling and the best results always come down to this exact thread. I don't flick so changing friction does little for me. Have you had any successes in workarounds?

Comment: I think you may be right. According to the following documentation from Microsoft:

"Windows currently does not provide a way to modify the Precision Touchpad (PTP) two-finger scrolling speed.
The Vertical Scrolling Speed setting in the classic Control Panel will not impact the PTP two-finger scrolling setting."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchpad-tuning-guidelines#two-finger-scrolling-speed

Answer (score 1):

There is no hack. At the moment the socalled precision touchpads just have no good driver, and two finger scrolling is essentially broken.

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly unrelated setting, but it does work:

**Control Panel > Mouse > Wheel (tab) > Vertical Scrolling**

Then increase the scrolled line number, hit Apply and check the scrolling speed.

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: not working for me either

Comment: This setting only applies when scrolling in programs and controls using line-by-line scrolling or similar - this is what "notched" scroll-wheels on mice do. What the OP is asking about are the newer "precision" touchpads and "notchless" mice-wheels that offer per-pixel scrolling. The behaviour of precision touchpads is different to notched touchpads.

Comment: This is 100% wrong, and you haven't tried this solution at all. You'll find it doesn't work. If you've ever used a modern precision trackpad you'll know what OP is talking about

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has a Synaptics touchpad, e.g. Lenovo, you can download, unzip and install (by clicking dpinst.exe) this driver: https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1mgx14w.zip
+ Don't forget to reboot.

This worked for me on Lenovo Yoga 920. I see no new service installed, and the "HID-compliant mouse" (which is the mislabeled trackpad) in the Device Manager still reports the old Microsoft driver.

But the scrolling has improved. (Not a Macbook-level but bearable enough.)